# Using an Enumeratum Enum in a Map does not work

Tags: scala, play-json, enumeratum

I have an Enumeration created with [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum):

```
sealed trait Language extends EnumEntry

object Language
  extends Enum[Language]
    with PlayInsensitiveJsonEnum[Language] {

  val values: IndexedSeq[Language] = findValues

  case object DE extends Language
  ...
}
```

If I use it in a Map it throws:

`No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for scala.collection.immutable.Map[finnova.bpf.api.entity.Language, java.lang.String] in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)`

Here is the definition:

```
case class I18nEntry(values: Map[Language, String])

object I18nEntry {
  implicit val jsonFormat: Format[I18nEntry] = Json.format[I18nEntry]
}
```

This here works:

```
case class I18nEntry(values: Map[String, String], language: Language)
```

Comment: The Play `Format` combinator for a `Map` will only be implicitly provided if your `Map` key is a `String`, as JSON object keys must be strings. It doesn't realize that `Language` is _eventually_ a `String`. Therefore you'd need to manually write your own `Reads` and `Writes` combinators for `Map[Language, String]`, or alternatively map `Language` to a `String` key such as you have `values: Map[String, String]` as you've done above.

Comment: @Lasf - thanks - can you put this in an answer - so I can accept it.

Comment: Sure, done. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Play `Format` converter for a `Map` will only be implicitly provided if your `Map` key is a `String`, as JSON object keys must be strings. It doesn't realize that `Language` is *eventually* a `String` (or, rather, a `JsString`). Therefore you'd need to manually write your own `Reads` and `Writes` converters for `Map[Language, String]`, or alternatively map `Language` to a `String` key such as you have `values: Map[String, String]` as you've done above. For what it's worth, the first solution would take roughly this structure:

```
val langMapReads: Reads[Map[Language, String]] = ???
val langMapWrites: Writes[Map[Language, String]] = ???
implicit val langMapFormat: Format[Map[Language, String]] = Format(langMapReads, langMapWrites)
```